# TestNg xml showing no error- but while running it gives Total tests run: 0

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have created a class file to print a message. I also configured TestNG xml to execute the class. Below is the contents of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="Sample test Suite">
   <test name="Sample test">
    <classes>
      <class name="signIn.MainMenu" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here is my source code of MainMenu.java:

```
package signIn; 
public class MainMenu { 
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        System.out.println("message"); 
    } 
}
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: We don't have any magic ball in hand. Any errors in console ? logs ?

Comment: ===============================================
Suite1
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0  Am getting this in console-

Comment: can you post the source code of your MainMenu.java class? Maybe you have some errors in your annotations

Comment: here is my source code-- package signIn;

public class MainMenu {
 public static void main(String args[]){
 
   
   System.out.println("message");
   
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a Test via annotations first,

so try this source instead:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MainMenu { 

    @Test
    public void test(){ 
       System.out.println("message"); 
    } 
}
```

and most important advice of all:

READ a tutorial on how to test with testNG!!

Comment: glad to be of help! (if you feel like it you can mark it as the correct answer and upvote it ;-)